# Overlay <div> according to attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine a HTML-Page with several `div` elements, which are all of the same `class` but have another attribute which distinguishes them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_1">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
  </div>
  <div class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_2">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
  </div>
  <div class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_3">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The attribute `foo` holds some kind of id, which is the integer behind the question mark. I need to extract that id from the `foo` attribute and store separately in another attribute. I figured this out (somehow) using JavaScript:

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
a[0].setAttribute("id", a[0].getAttribute("foo").match("(?<=anythingInHere_)[0-9]+"))
```

Furthermore, there is a JSON file which holds additional data to these extracted ids, for example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {"id": 1, "fill": "#0099ff"},
    {"id": 2, "fill": "#ff0066"},
    {"id": 3, "fill": "#00cc00"}
  ]
}
```

According to these colours mapped to the extracted ids, I want to overlay the respective `div` with a semi-transparent box, filled with the colour specified in the JSON.

And that is the point where I´m stuck. Probably a combination of JS and CSS will be needed and there has to be some kind of logic (probably JS, I guess) that places these semi-transparent boxes over the right `divs`.

You might have noticed that HTML, CSS and JS are not my major skills, but I rate this undertaking as possible - if not, please correct me. Otherwise I would be thankful for some help or general advice how to move on.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken few shortcuts but hope this is what you are looking for. If you need to overlay div with another, need to position div absolute.

```
<body>
  <div style="width:104px; height:142px;position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142" style="display:inline-block;">
    <span style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:104px; height:142px; display:inline-block; background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0)" class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_1" >
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="width:104px; height:142px;position:absolute; top:150px; left:0px">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142" style="display:inline-block;">
    <span style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:104px; height:142px; display:inline-block; background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0)" class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_2" >
    </span>

  </div>
  <div style="width:104px; height:142px;position:absolute; top:300px; left:0px">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142" style="display:inline-block;">
    <span style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:104px; height:142px; display:inline-block; background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.0)" class="myClass" foo="anythingInHere_3" >
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the script

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16), 
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
var obj = JSON.parse('{   "data": [     {"id": 1, "fill": "#0099ff"},    {"id": 2, "fill": "#ff0066"},    {"id": 3, "fill": "#00cc00"}  ]}');

for(var x=0;x<a.length;x++) 
    a[x].setAttribute("id", a[x].getAttribute("foo").match("(?<=anythingInHere_)[0-9]+"))

for(var x=0;x<obj.data.length;x++)
    document.getElementById("" + (x+1)).style.background = "rgba(" + hexToRgb(obj.data[x].fill).r + "," + hexToRgb(obj.data[x].fill).g + "," + hexToRgb(obj.data[x].fill).b + ",0.4)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need absolute positioning of DIV

Comment: Can you add an example of how to?